# window c++ app and html print preview

Tags: c++, pdf-generation, print-preview

I am working on a c++ browser app which will render html on the app screen.  I wanna to print the entire contents of the app screen (as internet explorers do). What is the proper, and easiest, way where I only pass handle to app window and it do print/pdf.

I googled this question but found only manual drawing. Is there some lib/technique where i pass handler of current window & it take care of printing text & images.

Comment: Which OS do you use? For Windows there exists the function [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Windows7, xp, vista.  VS 2010

Comment: If `PrintWindow` meets your needs I can post the answer.

Comment: Please It would be great help.  I tried this after start page. But it print blank page :-(.

Comment: <code> StartPage( hPrinter );if (hwnd == NULL)
  {
   return 0;
  }
  RECT rc;
  GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

  //create
  HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
  HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
  HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
  SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

  //Print to memory hdc
  PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY); </code>

Comment: All looks ok except for the flag `PW_CLIENTONLY` - don't use it, cause it's buggy. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows provides the function `PrintWindow` for getting an image of a window. Here is an example, taken from my sources, it places a resulting screenshot into clipboard (it takes into account that the function may not be supported on some Windows versions, but it seems unimportant to the question):

```
void PrintCapturedWindow(HWND hwnd)
{
  HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
  if (hdc)
  {
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    if (hdcMem)
    {
      RECT rc;
      GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

      HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right-rc.left, rc.bottom-rc.top);
      ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc); hdc = 0;
      if (hbitmap)
      {
          typedef BOOL WINAPI (* pPrintWindow)(HWND hwnd, HDC hdcBlt, UINT nFlags);
          pPrintWindow ppw;

          HMODULE user_hand = GetModuleHandle("user32.dll");
          ppw = (pPrintWindow)GetProcAddress(user_hand, "PrintWindow");
          if(ppw)
          {
            SelectObject(hdcMem, hbitmap);
            (*ppw)(hwnd, hdcMem, 0);
          }

          ::OpenClipboard(NULL);
          ::EmptyClipboard();
          ::SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbitmap);
          ::CloseClipboard();

          DeleteObject(hbitmap);
      }
      DeleteObject(hdcMem);
    }
    if(hdc != 0) ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try this.

Comment: :( still blank/empty page on printer. It look like something is missing in send image to printer. I check image is saving to clipboard properly. Let me try

Comment: Make sure you pass proper window handle. Also be aware of some nuances while taking copies of specific windows, for example, flash objects inside browsers may not render themselves propery.

Comment: Yes, If I copy past manually on mspaint its fine. I have to write some code to print that image on printer, which I am trying. Next thing its only taking image of visible area, is there any easy way to also include invisible area in scroll.   Thanks for your code I pickup clipboard part from there & it help to check that app is take screen shot correctly.

Comment: Yes, If I copy past manually on mspaint its fine. I have to write some code to print that image on printer, which I am trying. Next thing its only taking image of visible area, is there any easy way to also include invisible area in scroll.   Thanks for code sample I pickup clipboard part from there & it help to verify that app is take screen shot correctly and to identify that actual problem is printing image to printer.

Comment: As for printing clipped regions, it's not possible right away. It's possible by resizing window to such a size, that entire client area fits into it without scrollbars. But Windows imposes a limitation that any window can not be larger than screen size. In order to bypass this limitation I wrote a DLL and injected it into required processes.

Comment: @user1360135, BTW, according to your comments you called `CreateCompatibleDC`, but not for printer DC, why? If you want to print something directly, use printer's compatible DC as target. There exist [some examples](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/261009-bitmap-printing-tutorial-in-c-win32/).

Comment: I am using following before above one. Let me try what you have pointout. <code> PRINTDLG pdlg;
    memset( &pdlg, 0, sizeof( PRINTDLG ) );
    pdlg.lStructSize = sizeof( PRINTDLG );
    pdlg.Flags = PD_RETURNDEFAULT | PD_RETURNDC;
    PrintDlg( &pdlg ); DOCINFO di;
    HDC hPrinter = pdlg.hDC; memset( &di, 0, sizeof( di ) );
    di.lpszDocName = L"Printing";
    di.cbSize = sizeof( di );
    StartDoc( hPrinter, &di );
    StartPage( hPrinter );</code>

Comment: @user1360135, you should possibly look at Virtual Printer Drivers as well, [here is one of them](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageprinter/).

Comment: Thanks its very useful information. I thought I am facing problem in getting DIBits & printring via StretchDIBits. I am working on this & believe it will solve the issue. Am I right ? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you could probably post another question with exact description of your problem. Either provide more details about bitmap-related code, or formulate your applied task (without coding specifics) - perhaps there exist simple solution, for example, if you want to take snapshots of web-sites.

Comment: Solved. Thank you a lot. Its was the issue in getting & StretchDIBits. Now I have to only do scaling. Thanks for your continuous helpful replys. I really appreciated your support.